# How to make authkit session cookie HttpOnly in pylons?

Tags: python, cookies, pylons, authkit

I use authkit module with Pylons and I see that session cookie it sets (aptly named authkit) is not set to be HttpOnly.

Is there a simple way to make it HttpOnly? (By "simple" I mean the one that does not involve hacking authkit's code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not documented in authkit, because it only started working in Python 2.6 (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.Morsel)), but if you do have Python 2.6 then

```
authkit.cookie.params.httponly = true
```

in the config should work and do what you desire.

authkit internally uses a `Cookie.SimpleCookie`, and that's what limits the keys you can have for the `authkit.cookie.params.` -- up to Python 2.5 they were only the keys supported by the standard, [RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html), but in Python 2.6 the useful `httponly` extension was added -- which is how authkit gained support for it automatically... because, quite properly, it doesn't do its own checks but rather delegates all checks to `SimpleCookie`.

If you're stuck with Python 2.5 or earlier, then to make this work will require a little more effort (not changing authkit, but monkeypatching Python's Cookie.py, or better, if feasible, installing a newer version of Cookie.py from the Python 2.6 sources in a directory that's earlier in sys.path than the directory for Python's own standard library).

Comment: Awesome! I do have a python2.6, so config parameter did the trick. Thank you!